# Seeking Crew List for Prinz Oskar German Passenger Ship to Philadelphia, Pa circa 1914?

Tags: united-states, germany, manifest, ship, 1910s

I am looking for information about the crew on the German Passenger Ship ****Prinz Oskar** which was detained (circa 1914) and confiscated by the US in Philadelphia,PA (1917) as a result of WWI.

I am trying to find out where William Martin (b 7/1896 Germany, d 5/1970 New Jersey, USA), a crew member was from Germany.

Comment: What resources have you searched? Did he stay in the US after WW1 or did he go back to Europe and emigrate later? Have you found the WW2 Draft record? Was he naturalized? Did he have a social security number? Was an obituary published? As a crew member, he probably made other trips -- have you searched for other voyages? Or are you looking only for information on the detainment period?